# Jquery - need help on usage

Tags: php, jquery

Is this the right way of using the php script in the jquery function? 
The pathToTabImage variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
            pathToTabImage: '<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/ack.jpg';, //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
            alert(pathToTabImage);
            imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
            imageWidth: '125px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
            tabLocation: 'right',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
            speed: 600,                               //speed of animation
            action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
            topPos: '600px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
            leftPos: '550px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
            fixedPosition: false                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon.

`/images/ack.jpg';,`

to

`/images/ack.jpg',`

Also, this `alert` isn't doing you any favours either, and needs to go.

`alert(pathToTabImage);`

Comment: You also can avoid jumping in and out of php by concatenating your strings inline:

`pathToTabImage: '<?php echo $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/images/ack.jpg\', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css'; ?>'`

Comment: Although - why not just set it using CSS as the plugin-comment says? Would be a bit easier.

Answer (score -1):

It is one of the available ways to inject PHP codes, inside as HTML, CSS, or JS Document/Snippet. However, syntactically, there are few errors.

**PHP Error**

```
<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>
```

No selicolon on the end statement

**JavaScript Error**

```
pathToTabImage: '...';, //...
```

Unneeded semicolon, ending a statement in an incorrect way

```
alert(pathToTabImage);
```

Injecting an independant statement inside another statement